# Raspberry Pi ESC speed control

Tags: pwm

I've done ESC calibration using PWM from RPIO and set it's value to 2000 at first then 1000, after the long BIP it was set to go and when I set random value like 1300 or 1500 it would spin but only for a 5 seconds then slowly stops. How do I control it, add speed? I've done that motor_test.py that is on the internet and same results comes up.
It looks like this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-98xwAnkazI , and what now, how do I control its speed and why does it stop? Thanks

```
import time
from RPIO import 
PWM s=PWM.Servo()
s.set_mode(PIN,2000) 
time.sleep(5)
s.set_mode(PIN,2000)
time.sleep(5)
s.set_mode(PIN,1500)
```

Comment: Could you show the code you are using?  There is a lot of difference between the RPIO(.GPIO) module you mention and the RPi.GPIO module used by motortest.py.

Comment: @joan Thank you for reply, because I really need help here, I'm new to this. 
I've tried this:

import time

from RPIO import PWM

s=PWM.Servo()

s.set_mode(PIN,2000)

time.sleep(5)

s.set_mode(PIN,2000)

time.sleep(5)

s.set_mode(PIN,1500)

ESC 30A and A2212/13T motor

Comment: @joan 
It calibrates and starts spinning and after 5 seconds stops. It started with ok speed then lost it's power completely. That happens every time I try this, or anything similar. I've ordered a LiPo battery 2200mAh 11.1v but until it comes I'm using DC outlet power of 12v. I hope that is the problem. Also how do I control ESC, just by manipulating it with value in:

set_servo(PIN,value) ?

Comment: It's probably best if you edit your question to add the code.  That will allow the formatting to be maintained and will make it easier to understand.